# Creating site collection with javascript on office 365 (sharepoint online)

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, office365

I want to create a site collection using javascript but I could not find anything online.

Thank you.

Comment: Javascript is a clientside language - you will have difficulty creating a site collection from javascript..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a sharepoint hosted app

```
//create sp context and get root
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var rootWeb = clientContext.site.rootWeb();
this.clientContext.load(rootWeb);
this.clientContext.executeQUery();

//set web info
var webInfo = new SP.WebCreationInformation();
webInfo.set_webTemplate('YourTemplateName');
webInfo.set_description('Your site description');
webInfo.set_title('Your site tittle');
webInfo.set_url(siteUrl);
webInfo.set_language(yourLangCode);
this.rootWeb.get_webs().add(webInfo);
this.rootWeb.update();

// save site and set callbacks
this.clientContext.load(this.rootWeb);
this.clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
    Function.createDelegate(this, this.OnSiteCreationSuccess),
    Function.createDelegate(this, this.Error));
```

Keep in mind that your template MUST be saved with the langCode you use or it will throw a not found exception.